# Dropping rows that have string cointained in other rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given dataframe in this form:

```
 ID      A
130     Yes
130-1   Yes
130-2   Yes
200     No
201     No
201-10  No
201-101 Yes
201-22  Yes
300     No
```

I want to drop the rows that have value from `ID` column present in another string before the hyphen (`-`) in other rows
So based on this I would drop value `201` since there are `201-10`, `201-101` etc.

Expected output:

```
 ID      A
130-1   Yes
130-2   Yes
200     No
201-10  No
201-101 Yes
201-22  Yes
300     No
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and some bitwise operations.  This does rely on the values without hyphens being *before* the values with hyphens.

---

```
s = df['ID'].str.split('-').str[0]
m = s.duplicated(keep=False) ^ s.duplicated()

df[~m]
```

```
        ID    A
1    130-1  Yes
2    130-2  Yes
3      200   No
5   201-10   No
6  201-101  Yes
7   201-22  Yes
8      300   No
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do this for nested hyphens? I.e repeat above but if there are values like `201-10-1` and `201-10-2` then drop `201-10` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
g = df.ID.str.split('-').str[0]
is_child = g.eq(g.shift())
is_unique = g.groupby(g).transform('size').eq(1)
output = df[is_child | is_unique]
```

---

```
print(output)

      ID    A
1    130-1  Yes
2    130-2  Yes
3      200   No
5   201-10   No
6  201-101  Yes
7   201-22  Yes
8      300   No
```

---

Where:

```
df.assign(first_num=g,
         is_child=is_child,
         is_unique=is_unique)

       ID    A   first_num  is_child  is_unique
0      130  Yes       130     False      False
1    130-1  Yes       130      True      False
2    130-2  Yes       130      True      False
3      200   No       200     False       True
4      201   No       201     False      False
5   201-10   No       201      True      False
6  201-101  Yes       201      True      False
7   201-22  Yes       201      True      False
8      300   No       300     False       True
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do this for nested hyphens? I.e repeat above but if there are values like `201-10-1` and `201-10-2` then drop `201-10` as well?